# Get url in body_html odoo 9

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

Is it possible get web page url in xml template?

```
<field name="body_html">
    <![CDATA[
       <p>Get url here</p>
    ]]>
</field>
```

Note:

${object.id}

return id eg. 10

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, QWeb has some fallbacks when it comes to doing what would otherwise be a simple thing in Python, such as accessing `env` to `browse`, `search`, or get other data like `dbname` or the company parameters like `base_url`.

What I've done in the past is just create a helper to have Python do the dirty work for you so that you can keep QWeb simple.

**your_module/helpers/mixins.py**

```
class CanGenerateUrl:
    def generate_url(self):
        """
        Build the URL to the record's form view.
          - Base URL + Database Name + Record ID + Model Name

        :param self: any Odoo record browse object (with access to env, _cr, and _model)
        :return: string with url
        """
        self.ensure_one()
        base_url = self.env['ir.config_parameter'].get_param('web.base.url')
        if base_url and base_url[-1:] != '/':
            base_url += '/'
        db = self._cr.dbname
        return "{}web?db={}#id={}&view_type=form&model={}".format(base_url, db, self.id, self._model)
```

**your_module/models/model.py**

```
from openerp.addons.your_module.helpers.mixins import CanGenerateUrl

class YourModel(models.Model, CanGenerateUrl):
```

**your_module/views/report.xml**

```
<p><a href="${object.generate_url()}">${object.name or 'None'}<a/></p>
```

[Reports Documentation](http://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/reference/reports.html)

[QWeb Documentation](http://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/reference/qweb.html)